# Accessing a variable from a previous page load?

Tags: php, wordpress

I haven't touched PHP in years and have been asked to create an wordpress plugin.  I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way to do the following:

```
page1.php
---------
some_plugin(array(
    'option1' => 'some_data',
    'option2' => 'http://do_not_expose_to_client/'
});

generates
---------
<script language="text/javascript">
$.get('/page2.php', { data_set : 1 });
</script>

page2.php
---------
var options = get_options_from_page_1( $_GET['data_set'] );
```

Make sense I hope?  Basically I want to pass a PHP array from page1 --> page2 and am looking for a clean mechanism to do so.  I know I can drop data in a session var, but that just seems hacky and if I have multiple instances of this plugin on the page, I need to start tracking instance IDs, etc.

Comment: Everything to do with persisting state on a website is hacky, since the web was designed to be fundamentally stateless. Sessions are simply the simplest/cleanest method to produce a 'state' which can be persisted.

Comment: @Marc B - I realize that, I'm looking for a relatively clean solution -- a php library or whatnot -- where I can just do something like `store_data_in_db( array )` and `get_data_from_db( id )`

Comment: $_SESSION['your-variable']=value;

Comment: @cwolves: so what's wrong with `session_start(); $_SESSION['mydata'] = $array;`? It's built into PHP, and anything else you find is going to just do the same basically sort of thing anyways.

Comment: @Marc B - PHP session variables are per-server, I'm looking for something a bit more foolproof, preferably via memcache or a db if not.

Comment: The simple answer that I'm getting from these comments is that there is no good solution, which is about what I thought.  Was hoping someone had something creative.  Thanks :)

Comment: @cwolves: it's relatively easy to override the built-in file-based sessions and convert to something that's easily shared across servers. `session_set_save_handler()` is how you do the overrides.

Comment: @Marc B - Yeah, I know it's been done, and I've done similar in other languages.  Was looking for something off-the-shelf so I don't have to re-invent something this simple :)

Comment: Well it's either a question how you can do this or it's a configuration issue you're facing. But you should signal which direction you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a PHP "problem". Each script is executed in it's own process in your example and these do not share data.

An easy way to do so would be infact using `$_SESSION`, and you're right you must manage the data on your own. But you must so with any other method (e.g. via the database). I think session is pretty handy then.

Another method would be to encrypt the data, pass it with the request and then decrypt it again.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a problem. It is more or less what every web-interface I've seen does -- including multiple Java platforms, Python, and Perl. There are only so many ways to get the state to persist -- either you have a token on the server which the client matches (session), you have cookies, or you make a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request.

Comment: Yeah didn't mean it that "hard". Have put it in quotes to lighten this up. I think from the OPs perspective it's sort of a "problem" to find a solution for. It's solvable, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few ways to get a variable from one page to pass to another:

- Form variables -- GET/POST/(and to a lesser extent) PUT/DELETE
- Cookies
- Session
- HTTP Authentication headers (***DO NOT USE THESE FOR CONVEYING INFORMATION BETWEEN PAGES. THEY ARE FOR AUTHENTICATION ONLY***).

It sounds like you'll either want to use GET (add `?<varname>=<value>` (or `&<name>=<value>` if appending to other variables) to your URL -- it looks like you're close to getting that down) or you'll need to use Cookies or (personally, I think it better) SESSION.